# To find all subsets contain 7 elements from the set $ [{1, 2, ..., 14} ]$ such that the sum of the elements is divisible by 14

Tags: discrete-mathematics

anyone can help solve this problem?

How many subsets contain 7 elements from the set $[ {1, 2, ..., 14}]$ such that the sum of the elements is divisible by 14

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChrisLewis I have no idea

Comment: If you don't show any ideas, this question will probably be deleted. The easiest method is to code it. As a hint, though, try generalising: let $f(n)$ be the number of subsets of $\{1,...,2n\}$ whose sum is divisible by $2n$. Work out $f(n)$ for some small $n$. If you see a pattern, great; try to prove it. If not, try searching on OEIS for the sequence so you can read about it.

Comment: Since $14 = 2 \cdot 7$, you should try to determine conditions for divisibility by both $2$ and $7$.